# Is it possible? got NullPointerException when "return null"

Tags: java, android

I got randomly happened NullPointerException as follows:

```
03-28 11:32:36.557 E/AndroidRuntime( 3656): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-28 11:32:36.557 E/AndroidRuntime( 3656): java.lang.NullPointerException

03-28 11:32:36.557 E/AndroidRuntime( 3656):     at android.os.MessageQueue.pullNextLocked(MessageQueue.java:166)

03-28 11:32:36.557 E/AndroidRuntime( 3656):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:101)

03-28 11:32:36.557 E/AndroidRuntime( 3656):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:110)

03-28 11:32:36.557 E/AndroidRuntime( 3656):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

03-28 11:32:36.557 E/AndroidRuntime( 3656):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-28 11:32:36.557 E/AndroidRuntime( 3656):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

03-28 11:32:36.557 E/AndroidRuntime( 3656):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

03-28 11:32:36.557 E/AndroidRuntime( 3656):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

03-28 11:32:36.557 E/AndroidRuntime( 3656):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And I check MessageQueue.java:166, here is the code

```
final Message pullNextLocked(long now){
    Message msg = mMessages;
    if(msg != null){
        if(now>= msg.when){
            mMessages =msg.next;
            if(Config.LOGV) Log.v(
                "MessageQueue", "Returning message: "+ msg);
            return msg;
        }
    }

    return null; // 166     
 }
```

Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the right source file? The version running on the device might be different than the one in the SDK. The line you show cannot throw a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible for `return null;` to throw a `NullPointerException`.

IMO, the most likely explanation is that the Java source code you are looking at does not match the code that was being executed; i.e. that line 166 of the source code that was actually compiled is not that line.

- If `MessageQueue` is an Android class, then this could well be the issue that @Thilo notes; i.e. your Android SDK version doesn't match the Android version of device you are trying to debug.

  (And, now that I look more carefully, `MessageQueue` *is* an Android class: the package name says so clearly.  Duh!)
- Otherwise, take a hard look at the way you are building and deploying your app to the device.

(It is *theoretically* possible that a bug in the Java compiler or in Davlik is causing stack traces to report line numbers incorrectly.  But I think this explanation is *highly* unlikely.  That sort of bug that would have been found / fixed in a beta testing.  Or that we would have heard of ...)

Comment: He probably has the wrong source file. The version running on the device might be different than the one in the SDK.

Comment: I also want to believe I got wrong source code...
But the image is built by myself and so I am sure it is correct number of lines.

Comment: @Jett - it is not a build issue.  The issue is that your Android SDK is the wrong version for the device you are trying to debug.  Rebuilding won't fix this.  The fix is to use the right SDK version.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the method body is correct and that just the line number is wrong, then the only possible cause of a NPE anywhere in this particular method is that `msg.when` is actually a `Long` and is `null` which in turn can't be unboxed to `long`.

I'd at least fix the `if` statement accordingly.

```
if (msg.when != null && now >= msg.when) {
```